# Spring Boot 3 + Hibernate 6 migration: GCP Spanner Dialect latest v1.6.0 still refers to old ORM hibernate core

Tags: hibernate, google-cloud-platform, orm, google-cloud-spanner, spring-cloud-gcp

I'm in the process of upgrading a Spring Boot 2.7.7 + Hibernate 5 application to Spring Boot 3 and Hibernate 6. While updating I noticed that spring cloud spanner dialect latest v1.6.0 still refers to older hibernate package structure and coz of that getting as mentioned below and  [issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-spanner-hibernate/issues/556#issue-1592718169).

In Hibernate 6, As explained here this might be related to the new way of updating package structure for hibernate-core jar.
This dependency needs to be updated to refer latest hibernate-core jar which recently moved to "org.hibernate.orm"

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-spanner-hibernate/blob/230de173f5035a1f50072cbad88ef3e7117347f5/google-cloud-spanner-hibernate-dialect/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/spanner/hibernate/SpannerServiceContributor.java#L30

Spanner Dialect referring to old hibernate core

[image: 1]

Hibernate core updates

[image: 2]

I tried changing the dependencies manually to refer older hibernate-core however there is no luck. As you all may there are significant changes spring boot 3 brings in so had to fix this on priority as spring-web has critical vulnerability.
Git Issue: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-spanner-hibernate/issues/556#issue-1592718169

ERROR SpringApplication Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: org/hibernate/tool/hbm2ddl/UniqueConstraintSchemaUpdateStrategy

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/tool/hbm2ddl/UniqueConstraintSchemaUpdateStrategy
at com.google.cloud.spanner.hibernate.SpannerServiceContributor.contribute(SpannerServiceContributor.java:69)

Is there any workaround to fix this issue? or who can help form spanner hibernate dialect updates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cloud Spanner Hibernate dialect in [this repository only supports Hibernate 5.4](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-spanner-hibernate#google-cloud-spanner-dialect-for-hibernate-orm).

Hibernate 6.x comes with the Spanner dialect built-in: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/main/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/SpannerDialect.java

So the following should work:

1. Remove the dependency on `google-cloud-spanner-hibernate-dialect` from your project.
2. Update your dependencies to add Hibernate 6.x. This comes with the [`SpannerDialect` built-in](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/main/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/SpannerDialect.java).
3. Make sure that you also have a dependency declaration for `google-cloud-spanner-jdbc`.
4. Update your configuration so it uses `org.hibernate.dialect.SpannerDialect`. This is the fully qualified class name of the built-in Spanner dialect in Hibernate 6.x.

Comment: Thanks you for the suggestion! I posted same question on gcp-cloud spanner dialect repo and go the answer. It's working fine now. Just that few queries are not working with TIMESTAMP_DIFF() and HHH000315: Exception executing batch [com.google.cloud.spanner.jdbc.JdbcSqlExceptionFactory$JdbcSqlBatchUpdateException: Value has type BYTES which cannot be inserted into column client_info_id, which has type STRING